# Processing Multiple Files with Awk - Unwanted Lines Are Printing

Tags: awk

I'm trying to write a script to process two files. I'm getting stuck on a small detail that I've been unsuccessful in troubleshooting - hoping someone here can help!

I have two text files, the first with a single column and seven rows (all fruits). The second text file has two columns and seventeen rows (first column numbers, second column colors). My script is below - I've eliminated the rest of it, because after some troubleshooting I've found that the problem is here.

This script...:

```
BEGIN { FS = " " }

NR==FNR

{
    print NR "\t" FNR
}

END{}
```

When invoked with "awk -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt", produces this output:

apples
1   1
oranges
2   2
pears
3   3
grapes
4   4
mango
5   5
kiwi
6   6
banana
7   7
8   1
9   2
10  3
11  4
(truncated)

I don't understand what's happening here. The fields of file1 (the fruits) are being printed, but the only print statement in this script is printing the values of NR and FNR, which, from what I understand, are always numbers.

When I comment out the NR==FNR statement,

```
BEGIN { FS = " " }

#NR==FNR

{
    print NR "\t" FNR
}

END{}
```

The output is as expected:

1   1 
2   2
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   1
9   2
10  3
11  4
(truncated)

I need to use the NR==FNR statement in order to process multiple files.

Does anyone know what's happening here? Seems like such a basic issue (it's only 3 statements!), but I can't get rid of the damn fruits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NR==FNR` by itself is a pattern without an action. And the default action is to print the line (e.g `{print}`).

So awk sees `NR==FNR` as a test for the first file (as you indicated) and when it succeeds it then uses the default action.

So your script is effectively:

```
BEGIN { FS = " " }

NR==FNR {
    print
}

{
    print NR "\t" FNR
}

END{}
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense that a default action is to print. What I'm less clear on is why the action isn't the print NR line inside of the brackets. I thought that the syntax of awk was condition {action}. I may have a misunderstanding of a fundamental awk concept if that's not the case.

Comment: condition{action} is correct, but both are optional.  Default value of condition is true and default value of action is print.

Comment: Thank you both! This was driving me crazy.